Detalle con una llamada fetch
muy buenas tardes.
Estoy iniciando con php y javascript para poder mostrar información que viene del back end al front end, tengo en el javascript una variable donde almacena lo que viene de un input del html y esa variable tiene una función que busca información de una persona, el tema es que cuando se ejecuta la función me marca un error o no me muestra datos
javascript
txtCredencial.addEventListener('blur', buscarEmpleado);

const buscarEmpleado = async (e) => {
    let credencial = e.target.value;
    let data = {
        "credencial": credencial
    }
    const url = 'query_sql/getEmpleado.php';
    let opciones = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: data,
    };


    const respuesta = await fetch(url, opciones);
    console.log(respuesta);//Si hay conexion
    const datos = await respuesta.json();
    console.log(datos);//Arroja un error
};

php
<?php
include ('../../../../conf/conexion.php');  
$credencial = $_POST['credencial'];

    $sql_maetra = " SELECT T.*, A.mod_cve as mod, A.adsc_numero, A.adsc_numero as adscrip_numero,
                           P.puesto_grupo, P.puesto_rama, P.puesto_puesto, P.puesto_nivel,P.puesto_categoria,
                           P.puesto_descripcion, P.puesto_sdo_mensual,
                    CASE A.adsc_div_cve
                        WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT dir_nombre FROM adsc_direccion WHERE dir_cve=A.dir_cve)
                        WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT ger_nombre FROM adsc_gerencia WHERE ger_cve=A.ger_cve)
                        WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT depto_nombre FROM adsc_depto WHERE depto_cve=A.depto_cve)
                        WHEN 4 THEN (SELECT oficina_nombre FROM adsc_oficina  WHERE oficina_cve=A.of_cve)
                    END  || ' ' ||  
                    CASE mod_cve when 0 then  ' ' else M.mod_desc end AS adscrip_nom
                    FROM trabajador_maestra_nomina T 
                    INNER JOIN trab_puesto P ON (T.trab_cve_puesto=P.puesto_clave) 
                    INNER JOIN adscripcion A ON (T.trab_adscripcion=A.adsc_numero)
                    INNER JOIN modulo M ON (A.mod_cve=M.mod_clave)
                    WHERE T.trab_credencial = '$credencial' ";
    $qry_maetra =@pg_query($conexion,$sql_maetra);

$jsonstring =  json_encode($qry_maetra);
        echo $jsonstring;


Lo que pasa es que, si puedo tener una conexión correcta con el back end, hay una respuesta correcta, pero al tomar los datos de esa llamada con fecth me arroja un error que es el que está marcado como rojo, no sé si estoy mandando mal los datos o es otro tema, en teoría si hay una buena respuesta con el back end pero no puedo obtener esa información para después mostrarlo en pantalla

valida que tu respuesta en efecto sea un JSON, para ello ve a las herramientas de desarrollo en la pestana "networking" y has click en tu peticion, luego da click en "response", copia el contenido y valida que sea un JSON por ejemplo aca https://jsonlint.com/

Tienes dos salidas a consola con lo que has recibido, puedes incluir lo que produce la primera salida aquí en la pregunta.

Esto esta mal: const datos = await respuesta.json(); console.log(datos);//Arroja un error

y te explico, estas conviertiendo a JSON la respuesta la cual esta mal formada por que el header de php no esta definido como json ... en pocas palabras lo que recibes un es reponse request (objeto)... por ende javascript lo ve como un json mal formado...

te muestro como lo haria yo ...

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

Veamos los problemas que he detectado:

El cuerpo del fetch: Debe ser serializado como JSON.

La respuesta del PHP: La función json_encode necesita un arreglo asociativo, pero pg_query devuelve un recurso, no un arreglo. Debes obtener los datos de la consulta y convertirlos en un arreglo asociativo antes de codificarlos en JSON.


Ahora veamos el Codigo
El javascript deberia ser algo asi, buscamos serializar data:
txtCredencial.addEventListener('blur', buscarEmpleado);

const buscarEmpleado = async (e) => {
    let credencial = e.target.value;
    let data = {
        "credencial": credencial
    };

    const url = 'query_sql/getEmpleado.php';
    let opciones = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // Serializando el objeto data
    };

    try {
        const respuesta = await fetch(url, opciones);
        console.log(respuesta); // Si hay conexión
        if (!respuesta.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        const datos = await respuesta.json();
        console.log(datos); // Debería arrojar datos correctamente
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
};

en el PHP extraemos los datos de recurso:
include ('../../../../conf/conexion.php');  
$credencial = $_POST['credencial'];

$sql_maetra = " SELECT T.*, A.mod_cve as mod, A.adsc_numero, A.adsc_numero as adscrip_numero,
                       P.puesto_grupo, P.puesto_rama, P.puesto_puesto, P.puesto_nivel,P.puesto_categoria,
                       P.puesto_descripcion, P.puesto_sdo_mensual,
                CASE A.adsc_div_cve
                    WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT dir_nombre FROM adsc_direccion WHERE dir_cve=A.dir_cve)
                    WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT ger_nombre FROM adsc_gerencia WHERE ger_cve=A.ger_cve)
                    WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT depto_nombre FROM adsc_depto WHERE depto_cve=A.depto_cve)
                    WHEN 4 THEN (SELECT oficina_nombre FROM adsc_oficina  WHERE oficina_cve=A.of_cve)
                END  || ' ' ||  
                CASE mod_cve when 0 then  ' ' else M.mod_desc end AS adscrip_nom
                FROM trabajador_maestra_nomina T 
                INNER JOIN trab_puesto P ON (T.trab_cve_puesto=P.puesto_clave) 
                INNER JOIN adscripcion A ON (T.trab_adscripcion=A.adsc_numero)
                INNER JOIN modulo M ON (A.mod_cve=M.mod_clave)
                WHERE T.trab_credencial = '$credencial'";

$qry_maetra = pg_query($conexion, $sql_maetra);

if ($qry_maetra) {
    $result = pg_fetch_all($qry_maetra);
    $jsonstring = json_encode($result);
    echo $jsonstring;
} else {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Query failed']);
}

Estoy asumiendo que tienes un metodo pg_fetch_all para extraer datos de un recurso de base de datos, lo ideal y la finalidad es que $result si o si sea un array asociativo antes de pasarlo por el metodo `json_encode para evitar una respuesta vacia.
En este caso, el Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON apunta a ser una respuesta vacia ...
